# Autocad 2010 and Framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, autocad, cad

How can i assembly "NET Framework 4" with autocad 2010.
I have problems while using NETLOAD command.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use .NET 3.5 with AutoCAD 2010. 4.0 is only supported by AutoCAD 2012.

Answer (score 4):

AutoCAD 2010 can support *non* beta .Net 4.0 versions. If you edit the acad.exe.config file you may add this to get .Net 4.0 functionality:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

You can see for yourself in this AU material:
 [Using .NET 4.0 with AutoCAD](http://au.autodesk.com/?nd=material&session_material_id=6378)

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the AutoCAD install folder and edit the acad.exe.config file there you can add .NET 4.0 as a supported runtime:

```
<startup>
    <!-- v Add this line v -->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Note that advanced features of C# added in 4.0 wont work because they require all assemblies involved to be compiled for that version.

Answer (score 1):

Go To Project>yourappname properties>Compile>Advanced Compile options. And choose target .NET Framework 3.5