# C# .NET assembly dependency AutoCAD API

Tags: .net, autocad

I would like to build AutoCAD 2010 plugin on .NET 3.5 because .NET 4.0 is not support in 2010. After loading AutoCAD 2010 API library I can't build the solution because of a dependency. Could you help me who to figure it out?

Error Message:
Warning 15  The primary reference "acmgd" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework. PresbetonAPI

Comment: Its right in the error message, just take away the foof. `Warning The primary reference "acmgd" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on a .NET Framework assembly which has a higher version (4.0) than the version (2.0) in the current target framework`

Comment: How can I take away the foof? I think there are two foofs (2.0 and 4.0) in my project. The mscolib assembly reference is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop plugins with leveraging .NET 4.0 and AutoCAD 2010. It simply requires you changing the acad.exe.config.

See this previously posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579583/autocad-2010-and-framework-4-0/10766717#10766717).
And [this](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/using-net-framework-40-in-various-autocad-versions.html) elaborates more clearly the change.

Try that, look into it & let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path your references. If you are including acmgd.dll from a later version of AutoCAD, the compile will fail with the error reported in your question. The path should point to C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2010\acmgd.dll

Answer (score 0):

C# .NET assembly dependency AutoCAD API

1. accoremgd.dll
2. acdbmgd.dll
3. acmgd.dll

Dll files get from:- (Driver name)\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD (version)\acmgd.dll